# iPhone app crashes due to KVO

Tags: iphone, crash, key-value-observing

My app is crashing occasionally and when I see the crash logs this is what i see, i have truncated the rest because the rest of the stuff changes based on where my app is crashing.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32da1c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x338530ac NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate + 184
2   Foundation                      0x33852fc8 NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 56
3   Foundation                      0x33831e5c NSKeyValueWillChange + 544
4   Foundation                      0x3381e53c -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 120
```

I will give some background now

1. I have two classes where A have two variable and B have 3 variable
2. I am observing those variable in class C and D
3. The variable in class A and B keep changes due to different business logic flow in the app
4. There are two instance of class C which survive through out the lifecycle of the app as they are rootController for two of my tab in tabBarcontroller app.
5. Object of D gets created and destroyed very frequently based on what user is clicking on the app.
6. I am adding observer in init and remove observer in dealloc.

So far what I have realized is that as long as I make sure that it don't initialize D i think I don't see the crashes, but again I am not 100% sure, I will test more to see if that's the case.

But in the meantime if some one can give some pointer that would be great

Comment: Please post the init and dealloc methods for class D

Comment: You have a zombie - search Stack Overflow for NSZombieEnabled.

Comment: Thanks @jaminguys and @Reyfleck for looking into my question, yes i figured out that i wasn't removing one of the observer in my class D dealloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i figured out that i wasn't removing one of the observer in my class D dealloc.